# create oracle database and tables

Tags: database-design, oracle-apex

I've succesfully installed Oracle Application Express and also created Workspaces using home page `http://localhost:8080/apex`.

Now I want to create database and tables, but cannot find any instruction there.Below interface of home page.
[image]

I am good at phpmyadmin, but new at Oracle. Can someone tell instructions to create database and tables?
Thanks!

Comment: The SQL console should be under Manage Workspaces..

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have installed Oracle XE.

You have already a database available, otherwise you would not have a schema count 1.

in order to work with APEX as a developer you need to login with a user which has developer rights. I see that you have 2 users available. You can set up new users with the menu item "Manage Workspaces"->"Manage Developers and Users.

The following entry screen shall be seen if you use a developer user:

![Oracle Apex Developer Home] < Sorry could not post the image - stackflow does not allow me to do that>

Using the SQL Workshop menu you have the tools for creating tables etc. But by the way, it is much easier to use Oracle SQL Developer for doing the database stuff.

Hope the answer helps.

brgds,
Birthe